# Invocar método shared ajax y vb.net

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

¿Se puede usar ajax definiendo un método shared en una clase vb en vez de colocarlo en el codebehind de mi página? ¿Cómo seria la url para invocar el método ya que esta en una clase VB?

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "Prueba.aspx/ObtenerRegistros",
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(response) {
    var contactos = (typeof response.d) == 'string' ?
      eval('(' + response.d + ')') :
      response.d;

    $('#tablaContactos').empty();
    $('#tablaContactos').append('<tr>  
                                     <td><b>ID</b></td><td><b>Nombre</b></td>  
                                     <td><b>Telefono</b></td><td><b>EMail</b></td>  
                                 </tr>');

    for (var i = 0; i < contactos.length; i++) {
      $('#tablaContactos').append('<tr>' +
        '<td>' + contactos[i].IdContacto + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + contactos[i].Nombre + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + contactos[i].Telefono + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + contactos[i].Email + '</td>' +
        '</tr>');
    }
  },
  error: function(result) {
    alert('ERROR ' + result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

El tema es que necesitas que alguien exponga el codigo para poder ser acedidio mediente `http`, si solo lo defines en una clase queda oculto.

Es allí donde entra en juego el atributo `[WebMethod]` en el codebehind del aspx

[Calling ASP.Net WebMethod using jQuery AJAX](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx)

Otra alternativa seria usar servicio `asmx` (o `.svc` en el caso de usar `WCF`)

[Call (Consume) Web Service (ASMX) using jQuery AJAX in ASP.Net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-Consume-Web-Service-ASMX-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet.aspx)

Y una tercera definir un `handler`, podrias definir mediante codigo .net un handler que registras en el web.config para exponer en `http` indicando que extension asignas (por lo general `.ashx`)

Pero en las tres alternativas requieres poder exponer el código que defines en la clase para poder ser accedido mediante algo que `http` pueda resolver.